# C# MVC 4 Mulithreads and Web Requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

All,

I am creating a feature for our MVC 4 website that will allow users to generate a PDF report. These reports will take several minutes to generate so I don't wanna keep the user sitting there while I present several knock-knock jokes in a status window so I can go the traditional route of creating a job table, entering the job request and then poll the table for new job requests and ultimately generate the files that way.

I was told by my boss to just use a multithreded approach. In other words, spin off the the file generation task on a second thread. Is there any way to do this in a multi-threaded fashion instead? I am pretty certain that since the HTTP request is stateless, once the user terminates the session by a variety of means, least of which, closing the browser window, all threads would go away or could not be guaranteed to persist.

I did try to find a direct answer to my simple question on MSDN but struck out. I am certain this type of scenario is the same regardless of platform/framework but just checking.

Thanks in advance

Am I correct in this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're correct, manually creating threads is not the right approach.

IIS is in charge of managing the running threads, so it can recycle its application pools anytime (and your current thread/work be be lost). You shouldn't start background tasks by creating a thread.

See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Another great resource: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks

TL;DR:

The reliable way to handle this is complicated:

- Add the background work to a reliable queue, such as an Azure queue or MSMQ.
- Have an independent worker process that executes the work in the queue, such as an Azure WebJob, an Azure Worker Role, or a Win32 Service.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have pointed you in some directions you can take to implement this.

The first step should definitely to use async actions and tasks to start the generation.
Whether you want to run the document generation within the web process or in a separate process is a matter of scalability.

Any long running process like this has the potential to bring down a server unless properly guarded and/or throttled.

Imagine what would happen if your user gets bored waiting for the PDF and hits refresh, again and again. The next user has the same idea (because they always do). This can flood your server and, worst case, bring it down.

So consider carefully how you'll guard your resources and try to abort the generation if the user goes away.

Running the document generation inside the web process may work well enough if you have a well-behaved PDF generator and relatively low number of users. If you expect lots of users and need to do advanced stuff like dynamically scaling resources in the cloud, then queueing tasks for a separate process is definitely the way to go.